# how does tensorflow retraining last layer handle different image sizes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am running the [tensorflow retrain tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) but i cannot understand why the retrain images can be a different size from the images the model was originally trained on.  I looked into the [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) script that feeds the images to the model **but the code is not doing any kind of image resizing, it is directly [reading the image from disk](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L371) and immediately [feeds it to the model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L287)**.

Does anyone know how it can be using different sized images when doing last-layer training?

Comment: It might be doing on the fly image resizing?

Comment: what do you mean?  Are you suggesting that the model can accept variable size images?

Comment: not the model, but the code could be performing image preprocessing to either resize or subset the image before being sent to the model.  this is just a guess

Comment: what's the difference between jpeg_data_tensor, resized_input_tensor coming from create_inception_graph() ??

Comment: Also, if you ask for any distortion, cropping/resizing is done here : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L686

Comment: Yes, you can ask for distortion/cropping/resizing..  my question is why the retraining does not require resizing (which is not used by default in the script).

Comment: Generally, if you have a fully convolution network, the input image size is not an issue as the convolutional blocks are generally padded, so you get the same dimensions of these blocks no matter your input size. But if you have a non-padded convolutional blocks or a Fully Connected (FC) layer towards the end of the network, their dimensions are dependent on the input image size.

Comment: So a benefit of a fully convolutional network is that the image input size doesn't matter? (except performance would likely suffer for overly small images)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, the Inception models can be directly applied to a wide range of image sizes. This is possible because the last average-pooling before the dense layer is a **global** average-pool (rather than 3x3 or 2x2):

From https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/inception_model.py#L320 :

```
      shape = net.get_shape()
      net = ops.avg_pool(net, shape[1:3], padding='VALID', scope='pool')
```

This specifies the window of the pooling to be the whole image.

In other words, that pooling layer averages the features across the spatial dimensions, so `H x W x 2048` becomes `1 x 1 x 2048` regardless of `H` and `W`.

---

That said, in my experience, applying NNs at scales very different from how they were trained may cause some fall-off in accuracy (But the network should work)

Answer (score 1):

@anthonybell you are correct the code is not doing any image resize. But if you check the pretrained network there is a image resize layer

```
<tf.Tensor 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0' shape=() dtype=string>,
<tf.Tensor 'DecodeJpeg:0' shape=(?, ?, 3) dtype=uint8>,
<tf.Tensor 'Cast:0' shape=(?, ?, 3) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims/dim:0' shape=(1,) dtype=int32>,
<tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(1, ?, ?, 3) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'ResizeBilinear/size:0' shape=(2,) dtype=int32>,
<tf.Tensor 'ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(1, 299, 299, 3) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'Sub/y:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'Sub:0' shape=(1, 299, 299, 3) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'Mul/y:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'Mul:0' shape=(1, 299, 299, 3) dtype=float32>,
```

Network will accept images with any resolution and internally it is resized to 299x299

Comment: It seems like they have to do some kind of resize, because when you look at the convolutions the image at each layer gets smaller and smaller.. If my image was 8x8 to begin with what would it do when it got to 1x1..

Comment: That is because there are pooling layers sandwiched between convolution layers. If your input size is 8x8, resize layer will resize image to 299x299.